# Algorithm to split an array into minimal number of subarrays where sum of their elements is less than or equal a given one

Tags: algorithms, sorting, dynamic-programming, arrays, maximum-subarray

Title of the question pretty much summarises the question. Here is a concrete example of what I'm trying to achieve with no success.
Let's say we have a sorted list (but sorted is not a requirement) `L = [1,3,20,100,150,200,260]` and `K = 260`. I need a function `f(L,K)` which given this list and `K` will return a list `B = [[1,3,20,200],[100,150],[260]]`. As you see if we just group elements in their sorting order with their sum <= `K` like this: `[[1,3,20,100], [150], [200], [260]]` we will have 4 subarrays but it's possible to have 3.
This algorithm may be useful for instance to make a compact linear stack layout of some UI elements of different lengths with min number of lines of those elements.

UPD. I decided to remove a word "efficient" from the question because this looks like an NP-hard problem. To be clear I need more or less optimal but correct solution. Numbers will not be large because I'm talking about this problem in the context of practical task (efficient UI layout) that's why `K` and list elements will be a small numbers in the range [0, ..., ~1000].
I put a label "dynamic programming" because I think that this problem may be solved with dynamic programming approach and as was mentioned in the first comment is related to bin packing problem.

Comment: Start exploring solutions to bin packing problem

Comment: Care to share your thoughts about "the greedy approach"?

Comment: Your question is NP-hard by an easy reduction from PARTITION. That doesn't mean you can't solve it in practice if the numbers are small.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Could you please elaborate more on `"by an easy reduction from PARTITION"`. I'm currently stuck and can't come up with just a right algorithm. I'm not even talking about efficiency.

Comment: @greybeard I don't have any thoughts about "greedy approach" and didn't even mentioned this in my question. Could you please tell what did you mean?
I put a label "dynamic programming" because I have a feeling that this problem may be solved with dynamic programming approach and as was mentioned in the first comment is related to bin packing and knapsack problems.

Comment: Are all values positive? *Greedy* approach: add to each bin the highest values possible. For your example: [[260], [200, 20, 3, 1], [150, 100]]. ([Best Fit decreasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing#Analysis_of_approximate_algorithms))

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem#Exact_algorithm

Comment: @greybeard does your approach always provides the best fit?

Comment: @nomanpouigt You might try and follow links, if not "informed common sense".